# Triggering a Msg when page loads (elm 0.18)

Tags: onload, elm

If I want to trigger an update `SomeAction` with a button in elm (0.18), I would do it like this:

```
myView : Html Msg
myView =
    div []
        [ button [ onClick SomeAction ] [ text "Some Action" ]
        ]
```

I want `SomeAction` to fire when myView renders.  How do I do something like this:

```
myView : Html Msg
myView =
    div [ onLoad SomeAction ]
        []
```

Comment: seems like onLoad is not implemented yet http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.1/Html-Events

Comment: you can refactor your model and define a Boolean as a condition to render this *myView* under *view*, then you can trigger *SomeAction* through your *Msg*

Comment: @Anzel If you can elaborate on this and provide a good example, I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Is rendering `myView` based on some conditions? If yes, then leverage that to trigger the `SomeAction`. I will include a mini sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, if your rendering `myView` is based on a condition, you can leverage this into your *Model* and do some action when it's supposed to show.

Mini sample for a pseudo code:

```
import Html exposing (beginnerProgram, div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Debug


main =
  Html.program
    { init = (init, Cmd.none)
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.none


type alias Model =
  { value: Int
  , show: Bool
  }


init : Model 
init = 
  Model 0 False


viewButton model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]


view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick ShowMe ] [ text <| if model.show then "Hide" else "Show" ]
    , if model.show then viewButton model else text ""
    ]


type Msg 
  = NoOp
  | Increment 
  | Decrement
  | ShowMe


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    NoOp -> (model, Cmd.none)

    Increment ->
      ({ model | value = model.value + 1 }, Cmd.none)

    Decrement ->
      ({ model | value = model.value - 1 }, Cmd.none)

    ShowMe ->
      -- leverage Cmd msg to do some action
      ({ model | show = not model.show }, someAction model.show)


someAction : Bool -> Cmd msg
someAction showing =
    -- or do some other things here
    let _ = Debug.log "show before click" showing
    in Cmd.none
```

Answer (score 1):

This is dirty but it works... do an animation that practically does nothing and listen on "animationend" and "webkitanimationend".

```
          Html.div
                [ Html.style [ ( "display", "inline-block" ), ( "animation", "pulse 0.1s" ) ]
                , Html.Events.on "webkitAnimationEnd" 
                   (Json.Decode.succeed (FancyMessageHere)
                ]
                []
```

Also have a dummy pulse in your CSS:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0%   {background-color: white;}
    100% {background-color: white;}
}
```